# How to convert dictionary (from imported Excel file/sheets) into multiple dataframes?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dictionary

I'm trying to import this file and read each of the sheets (each sheet is a year of data), and then save each sheet as its own dataframe objects named after each year. See the code below (note that there are 2 additional sheets that aren't years, hence the deletes).

```
url = 'https://www.hudexchange.info/resources/documents/2007-2019-PIT-Counts-by-CoC.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(url, None)
del pit['CoC Mergers']
del pit['Revisions']
```

After importing the file as a dictionary, I don't know how to convert it into separate dataframes named after the years (keys) below. I know you can call individual dataframes using their key via df['2019'], etc., but without being their own objects, it's much more difficult to use functions or for loops in the later code.

```
dict_keys(['2019', '2018', '2017', '2016', '2015', '2014', '2013', '2012', '2011', '2010', '2009', '2008', '2007'])
```

Note that I've been using a more manual method that serves the purpose, below. However, it's really slow, and I'm hoping for a scalable option when there are too many sheets to import this manually? And/or when the dataset gets updated and more years are added.

```
pit = 'https://www.hudexchange.info/resources/documents/2007-2019-PIT-Counts-by-CoC.xlsx'

2010=pd.read_excel(url, '2010')
2011=pd.read_excel(url, '2011')
2012=pd.read_excel(url, '2012')
2013=pd.read_excel(url, '2013')
2014=pd.read_excel(url, '2014')
2015=pd.read_excel(url, '2015')
2016=pd.read_excel(url, '2016')
2017=pd.read_excel(url, '2017')
2018=pd.read_excel(url, '2018')
2019=pd.read_excel(url, '2019')
```

Comment: whats the end goal  ? why do you want n number of variables? just hold it in a dictionary or list i.e `{sheet_name : dataframe for sheet_name, dataframe in pit.items()}`

Comment: End goal is to eventually concatenate them into one dataset row-wise--but the problem is their column names/column numbers don't match across each sheet, so they need to be individually cleaned first.

Comment: then the above should work - if you assign it to a variable called `dfs` you can call it like `dfs['2019']`

Comment: Thanks thanks, I've been using this method for calling each df individually. But was hoping there was an easy automatic solution for creating new df objects instead of keeping them nested in the dictionary (as my code it set up to iterate through multiple dataframes). Hm, maybe I should just stick with the manual import.

Answer (score 0):

That is an example of how you can open `Sheets` from the file into multiple `DataFrames`

```
df_main= pd.ExcelFile('path_to_file.xls')
df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, '2019')
df2 = pd.read_excel(xls, '2018')
```

Comment: Sorry I should clarify--I was using this method previously, and it serves the purpose. But I'm looking for a scalable option when there are too many sheets to import this manually? And/or when the dataset gets updated and more years are added.